# stm32f4 button debouncing when pressing

Tags: debouncing, stm32f4

I'm working on an "accurate" button. I mean when I press the button it will not debounce. Can I achieve this by using only software ?

I'm using STM32F4 MCU.

Thank you all...

Comment: Yes but I asked how to code for this so I mean question about coding :)

Comment: The answer is yes anyway. Here is a list that will help you: http://hackaday.com/2010/11/09/debounce-code-one-post-to-rule-them-all/.